# 'NSInvalidArgumentException' while running an application using NSURL and NSJSON

Tags: ios, json, url, exception

I have designed an app, which would have a button and three labels.

When the button is pressed, an URL is called. The JSON representation of the URL is as follow:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "50c87e8a1898044ea1458e4c",
    "value": "10",
    "time": "12:10",
    "date": "12.12.12"
  },
  {
    "_id": "50c87f311898044ea1458e4d",
    "value": "12",
    "time": "13:15",
    "date": "12.12.12"
  }
]
```

I also have three label in my app, that would display the value, time and date.

The code for my app is as follow:

```
-(IBAction)getrequest:(id)sender
{
    NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/lights"];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    //fetch the data to the JSON Foundation opject.
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:)
                           withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
}

- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    NSError *e = nil;
    NSMutableArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];
    NSLog(@"%@", json);
        [self processData:json];
}

-(void)processData:(NSDictionary *) JSONObject{
    NSString        *value = [JSONObject valueForKey:@"value"];
    NSString        *date    = [JSONObject valueForKey:@"date"];
     NSString        *time    = [JSONObject valueForKey:@"time"];


    NSLog(@"value: %@", value);
    NSLog(@"date: %@", date);
    NSLog(@"time: %@", time);

    _value.text = value;
    _date.text = date;
    _time.text = time;

}
```

The code compiles and builds without any error, but when I press the button in my simulator I get an exception as follow:

```
2012-12-12 14:16:21.115 Sensor_visulization[7956:11303] value: (
    10,
    12
)
2012-12-12 14:16:21.116 Sensor_visulization[7956:11303] date: (
    "12.12.12",
    "12.12.12"
)
2012-12-12 14:16:21.116 Sensor_visulization[7956:11303] time: (
    "12:10",
    "13:15"
)
2012-12-12 14:16:21.116 Sensor_visulization[7956:11303] -[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7191a30
2012-12-12 14:16:21.117 Sensor_visulization[7956:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7191a30'
```

Is there any problem with my json parser?

Can I store all the values, time, date in an array?

and display the last item in the array on the label?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Everything looks fine except at the end, where you're trying to set `_value.text` (presumably a `NSString` property) to `value` (which is an array, not a string). How precisely do you want to represent the array in that `NSString`? You could do `_value.text = [value description];` or `_value.text = [value componentsJoinedByString:@", "];` or whatever.

Comment: @Rob I got it working by the method, described below. But thanks anyway. But how can I get all the values in a single array and all the time in a separate array and sketch a graph, with values on one axis and time on another?

Comment: See my updated answer which shows how to save the three separate arrays (as well as retrieving the last object for your UI controls). Regarding the sketching of a graph, it depends upon how you're drawing charts and that is an entirely different question. To that end, I'd suggest you submit another question on that topic, showing examples of what you've tried in terms of plotting this data. But hopefully we've solved your question about how to get an array of values.

Comment: By the way, if this is for a charting app having separate arrays for dates and times might not be entirely useful. You probably want to combine those two into a single array of datetime objects (perhaps `NSDate` objects). See my updated answer for an example of how to combine them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a general confusion about what `valueForKey` does when your `json` object is an array of dictionary entries. Midhun's answer, solves it one way, by passing only one dictionary entry to `processData` (which was a logical solution because your original code's declaration of `NSString *value` clearly implied that you were expecting only one dictionary entry to be passed to it).

But, if you want to get arrays for all three dictionary keys for your array of dictionaries, you'd use your original `fetchedData`, and use `valueForKey` against the original `json` object to return `NSArray` objects. To do that, I'd suggest, a couple of slight modifications of your original code:

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    NSError *e = nil;
    NSMutableArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];
    NSLog(@"%@", json);
    [self processData:json];
}

-(void)processData:(NSDictionary *) JSONObject{

    // get the three array structures

    NSArray *value = [JSONObject valueForKey:@"value"];
    NSArray *date  = [JSONObject valueForKey:@"date"];
    NSArray *time  = [JSONObject valueForKey:@"time"];

    // these log statements demonstrate that value, date, and time are arrays

    NSLog(@"value: %@", value);
    NSLog(@"date:  %@", date);
    NSLog(@"time:  %@", time);

    // now, let's grab the last object from each to populate our controls

    _value.text = [value lastObject];
    _date.text = [date lastObject];
    _time.text = [time lastObject];
}
```

---

By the way, in one of your comments, you made a parenthetical reference to wanting to chart these results. If that's the case, I might imagine that you need the dates and times combined, into `NSDate` objects. If you want them as `NSDate` objects, you could:

```
-(void)processData:(NSDictionary *) JSONObject{

    // get the values

    NSArray *value = [JSONObject valueForKey:@"value"];

    // get the datetimes

    NSMutableArray *datetimes = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.dateFormat = @"dd.MM.yy HH:mm";
    formatter.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];

    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in JSONObject)
    {
        NSString *datetimeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"date"], [dictionary objectForKey:@"time"]];
        NSDate *datetime = [formatter dateFromString:datetimeString];
        [datetimes addObject:datetime];
    }

    NSLog(@"values=%@", values);
    NSLog(@"datetimes=%@", datetimes);
```

Because your sample data features today's unique date, `12/12/12`, I wasn't able to determine your date format, so I guessed you're using `dd.MM.yy`, but obviously use whatever date format string makes sense for your JSON data.

Comment: when I add your code, I get an error "no visible interface for NSString declares the selector lastobject" Any help??

Comment: @Kishorepandey My code was based upon your original question in which you were `NSLog`'ing the `value` variable and you were getting an array. If you have an array and you want to grab the last object in that array, you use the code of my answer. I wonder if you tried using my code after you had already integrated Midhun MP's answer, which wouldn't work. See my updated answer in which I include the entire `processData` method, to remove any ambiguity, and which I believe accomplishes both goals, getting the array of all three types, but also retrieving the last one for your three controls.

Comment: That was awesomeness!! Thanks a lot mate. I just have a last query, Which IOS class would you prefer to plot these elements in the array. With values on x axis and time on y? Any suggestions??

Comment: @Kishorepandey I've never done charting, but Core Plot is often discussed in this context. If you search StackOverflow, you'll see tons of excellent answers.

Answer (score 1):

`json` is a `NSMutableArray` you are passing it to `processData` method as `NSDictionary` parameter.

```
 NSMutableArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];
```

Change the method call like:

```
[self processData:[json objectAtIndex:0]];
```

The above will display first element. If you need to display the **last element** use:

```
[self processData:[json objectAtIndex:[json count]-1]];
```

Comment: thanks a lot mate. It worked. I also have a small query, How can I get all the elements in an array. For eg: An array consisting of values, an array of date and an array for time? I would like to collect atleast the last five elements in an array. Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: @Kishorepandey: with pleasure dude :)

Comment: mate, while using it, I am calling the function only for the last element in the array. How can I keep all the elements in the array value, date, time intact and just display the last element in _value.text, _date.text, _time.text? Any help would be really appreciated. The reason why I would like to keep these elements in array is cause, I would be using it further to generate plots.